# Order of columns in an index

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I am working on a database with large number of rows (6 Mil+).

This table has a composite primary key on two columns.

It also has separate index on each of those fields as there are queries that require this. Obviously, one of those indexes (indices?) is redundant and slowing down performance for write operations.

How do I find out which one is redundant? I understand the first column of a primary key is already indexed and need not be indexed separately. Is that correct? If so, is there a query I can run to find out which is the first one in the list?

Comment: You are not asking the right question IMO.  You added these indices for a reason.  What was the reason?  And why not add a true composite index covering both columns?

Comment: As I said those indices are needed for various queries so there is no doubt that we need indices on both columns. However, if the composite index can also be used as index on one of the columns then I do not need to create separate indices on both columns separately.

See this picture to explain the situation: https://i.imgur.com/NrsOa0q.png

Now, my question is one index seems redundant. How do I find which one?

Comment: My understanding is that if you have a composite index on `(a, b)` then it also works on `a` alone, but not `b`.

Comment: That's what I am thinking. How do I find out which one is column a in this case. I don't want to depend on what phpmyadmin tells me.

Comment: Use `SHOW INDEX`.  Can't you search for this yourself?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. My question is can we depend on the order displayed by those queries or is there anything else (like recreating the table) that needs to be done to make sure the order of the columns shown is correct.

Comment: I see no data, SQL code, or table structure in your question.  I won't comment further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW INDEXES FROM tablename` will include a `Seq_in_index` column, which tells you which is first (aka, left most) column, second column, etc.

Therefore, whichever column is listed with a value of `1` for `Seq_in_index` is the column that does not need it's own single column index.

You can also use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` to see the index listed from left to right, and that order displayed correctly represents the order of columns in the index.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to make sure was dependable.

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` gives you all the indexes, in their established order.

You don't need `INDEX(a)` because the column(s) in it are the first column(s) in the `INDEX(a,b)`,

That applies to `INDEX` / `UNIQUE` / `PRIMARY KEY` in `(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the first column of a primary key is already indexed

Erm, no. All the columns in the primary key are indexed.

An explanation of how indexes work is stretching the scope of a post here, and the question of which indexes to put on your table is **way** too broad.

Suppose you have a primary key defined on attributes a,b,c. This index can be used for queries with predicates

- a
- a and b
- a and b and c

But (at least, the last time I checked) it would not be used for a query with predicates

- b
- b and c

The optimizer will only ever use one index for each table in a query.

The right indexes depend on the volume of data, the cardinality of the data and the frequency and combination of predicates in your queries. There are execution and storage overheads when you start adding indexes, even just for select operations badly designed indexes can make your query slower than it would run without indexes.

Comment: That's what I meant when I say that adding a separate index on "a" would be redundant. My question is if I do "show index" will that show me the indices in order or is there anything specific do I need to do. I guess I am just making it harder than it is and show index should have worked.